# How do you run a certain class function based off the number it end in

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

wondering if there's any way to run a certain function based off the arguments we give an object. For example, if we pass 1, it will run function_1, but if we pass 2 it will run function_2. Like so:

```
class my_Class:
    def func(self, num):
        self.__dict__[f"func_{num}"](num)

    def func_1(self, num):
        print("test", num)

    def func_2(self, num):
        print("test", num)


class_obj = my_Class()
class_obj.func(1)
class_obj.func(2)
```

The output I'd want here is:

```
test 1
test 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution you can try, using `getattr`

```
class my_Class:
    def func(self, num):
        self.__dict__[f"func_{num}"](num)

    def func_1(self, num):
        print("test", num)

    def func_2(self, num):
        print("test", num)

    def run(self, func_id):  # <-- wrapper that call's the inner function based on id
        getattr(self, f"func_{func_id}")(func_id)


class_obj = my_Class()
class_obj.run(1)  # <-- Call wrapper instead with function idx
class_obj.run(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
class my_Class:
    def func(self, num):
        getattr(self,"func_"+str(num))(num)

    def func_1(self, num):
        print("test", num)

    def func_2(self, num):
        print("test", num)


class_obj = my_Class()
class_obj.func(1)
class_obj.func(2)
```

**Output:**

```
test 1
test 2
```

**Explination**

You can use the function, `getattr()` to call a function from a string, you can later on change that string to any format you want to be the source (dictionary, list, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a map using list/tuple/dictionary that points to the functions, something like:

```py
class MyClass:  # search pep8 to see the conventional way of writing class names in python
    def __init__(self):
        self.functions_map = (self.func_1, self.func_2)

    def func(self, functions_index, *args):
        self.functions_map[functions_index](*args)

    def func_1(self, num):
        print("test", num)

    def func_2(self, num):
        print("test", num)
```

And then, in order to call the functions do something like:

```py
class_obj = MyClass()
class_obj.func(0, 3)  # remember indexes start at 0, and not 1
class_obj.func(1, 5)
```

Where 3 and 5 are the numbers being passed to func_1 and func_2 as arguments

Answer (score 0):

with an if or switch case

e.g.

```
class my_Class:
def func(self, num):
    if(num == 1):
        self.func_1(num)
    if(num == 2):
        self.func_2(num)

def func_1(self, num):
    print("test", num)

def func_2(self, num):
    print("test", num)

class_obj = my_Class()
class_obj.func(1)
class_obj.func(2)
```